# Can object be omitted in participial construction?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

"Hyperfocus requires willpower and mental energy to activate, drawing from the limited supply we have to make it through the day."

In this sentence, I think the things that are drawn from the limited supply are willpower and mental energy. But then, is it okay to omit the repetitive object from the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are omitting a plural, it would make more sense to say "...drawing from the limited **supplies** we have to make it through the day."

I think this would be clear to most native speakers that you are referencing the two objects mentioned previously.